# Returning pixel coordinates of opengl shapes on android screen

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to increment count by 1 when a shape is no longer on the screen. The problem is i need to know where the vertices of my shape is on the screen of my android device. How do i compute this? What ive found is where the vertices are when the polygon was drawn.

```
In glrenderer class  

     int count = 0;
        int h, w;

    public MyGLRenderer() {
        h = MyGLSurfaceView.height;
        w = MyGLSurfaceView.width;
}


public void onScreen(int a) {

        for (int i = 0; i < star[a].vertices.length; i+=3) {
            Log.i("vert", String.valueOf(star[a].vertices[i]));//i found where vertices are in relation to other vertices
            float starW = (star[a].vertices[i] * (w/2)) + (w/2) * GL10.GL_PROJECTION * GL10.GL_MODELVIEW;//i need to know where vertices are on thhe screen
        float starH = (star[a].vertices[i+1] * (h/2)) + (h/2) * GL10.GL_PROJECTION * GL10.GL_MODELVIEW;

            if (    starW >= w ||
                    starW <= 0 ||
                    starH >= h ||
                    starH <= 0){

                count++;
               // Log.i("count", String.valueOf(count));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my glsurfaceview class i have

```
public static int height, width;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    height = size.y;
    width = size.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work:

```
float starW = (star[a].vertices[i] * (w/2)) + (w/2) * GL10.GL_PROJECTION * GL10.GL_MODELVIEW;
float starH = (star[a].vertices[i+1] * (h/2)) + (h/2) * GL10.GL_PROJECTION * GL10.GL_MODELVIEW;
```

`GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_MODELVIEW` are **enum values**, which are possible argument values for `glMatrixMode()`. They are most definitely **not** matrices.

What you're trying to do here is apply the projection and modelview matrices in your own code. The easiest way to have the current values of those matrices is to keep them around in your own code. After all, you did specify them, so you should know what they are.

If you do want to query the current values of these matrices, the proper way to do that is:

```
float[] mvMat = new float[16];
GL11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvMat);
float[] projMat = new float[16];
GL11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMat);
```

Once you have those matrices, you can start multiplying them with your vertex coordinates. You can either write your own code for that, or use the [android.opengl.Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html) class. `multiplyMM()` and `multiplyMV()` are methods from that class that could come in handy for this job.

Beyond that, here's the unavoidable remark when I see people using ES 1.x: In my opinion, this has to be considered an obsolete API at this point. Unless you have a very good reason to use it, I strongly recommend to use ES 2.0 or higher.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have since update my code so it uses opengl es 2 and it draws my shapes fine. Also i have a better understanding view and projection matrices and was able to apply them.